# Update a table from a geodatabse

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server, update

I use a Geodatabase on SQL Server, on which I base myself to configure tables of the bors and maps.

I tried to modify a few items in a table in this Geodatabase with a simple query (UPDATE...SET). I manage to visualize the changes in my table but after 10 min, I lose my modifications and I note that it displays the old values ​​to me. Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to specify whether the feature class has been registered as versioned  in the geodatabase. If it has, then you have corrupted your database integrity with direct SQL upates. The versioned model supports SQL edits, but only through versioned views. There's tons of documentation on this; I suggest you start with a search on "Versioning 101".